# Fast verification of solution to x'Ax<C

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Assume we have some complex vector with N dimensions $\vec x$. We need to verify if this is a valid solution to:

$\vec x^HA\vec x<C$

where $A$ is a Hermitian matrix and $C$ is some real constant. The $^H$ denotes complex conjugate and transpose. The trivial solution of just multiplying everything together takes $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$.

I have many different vectors $\vec x$ to check, so this isn't an option. Since $A$ is known in advanced, I wanted to ask if there's some faster algorithm I can use for a large number of vectors. If it helps, the diagonal of $A$ is zeros and its eigenvalues are a mix of both positive and negative (but not zeros).

Edit: Since $A$ is known in advance, you can use any SVD, eigenvalue decomposition or other actions on it. Moreover, I can assume that the norm of $\vec x$ is 1 for all the vectors.

Comment: 1. Do you have the eigenvectors? 2. Divide both sides by $\| x \|^2$; now how does $C$ compare to the eigenvalues of $A$? If the new $C$ is less than most of the eigenvalues or more than most of the eigenvalues, then you can compute projections on just a few eigenvectors.

Comment: Can we use the unitary diagonalization $A = VD V^H$?

Comment: The matrix $A$ is known in advance, so I can do anything I want with it - SVD, eigenvalue decomposition, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the eigenvalue decomposition and normalize the problem by dividing both sides by $\| x \|^2$. If now $C$ is larger than all eigenvalues, then the inequality holds; if it is smaller than all eigenvalues, then the inequality doesn't hold. Similarly, normalize the eigenvectors.

Suppose that $C$ is larger than all the nonzero eigenvalues except $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$. Begin by computing the projection coefficient $c_1$ onto $v_1$. If $c_1^2 \lambda_1+(1-c_1^2)\lambda_N \geq C$ then the inequality fails. Otherwise repeat: replace $x$ by $x-c_1 v_1$, $A$ by $A-\lambda_1 v_1 v_1^T$, and $C$ by $C-c_1^2\lambda_1$ and continue.

You can proceed from the other end if you anticipate the inequality succeeding. You could also proceed from *both* directions (perhaps in parallel, perhaps just alternating back and forth serially).

Answer (score 2):

Let $d_i$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$ with $d_1>d_2> \cdots > d_n$. Let $v_i$ be the (orthonormal) associated eigenvectors.

Note that
$$
x^HAx = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i |x^Hv_i|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} d_i |x^H v_i|^2 + d_k\sum_{i=k}^n \left(x^Hx - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}|x^H v_i|^2 \right)
$$
It suffices to verify that for some value of $k$, the quantity on the right is smaller than $C$.

Comment: Note that in the worst case, we will need $O(N^2)$ computations  anyway